# Configurar Tomcat com SSL

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https, localhost

Eu segui o tutorial no site [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration) que manda basicamente fazer 2 coisas:

- Criar um .keystore com password changeit através do Keytool.exe. Salvei o arquivo resultate em C:\Users\Vinicius
- Descomentar e modificar o conector do **server.xml** localizado em **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf**

E ficou assim:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"        keystoreFile="C:\Users\Vinicius\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Após isso, em teoria, é só acessar a minha pagina pelo `https://localhost:8443/` mas recebo o erro:

> A conexão com localhost foi recusada.

Fiz algo errado?

Comment: Veja o erro no catalina.out e poste aqui

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar um certificado no tomcat siga essas etapas:

Primeiramente você deve criar um p12 com o openssl assim:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey chavePrivada.pem -out
>   tomcat.p12 -name tomcat

será solicitado uma senha para o keystore, coloque changeit.

Após isso você devera criar o seu JKS dessa maneira:

> keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit
>   -destkeystore tomcat.jks -srckeystore tomcat.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias tomcat

Com isso será criado um arquivo chamado `tomcat.jks`

Logo você devera configurar o `server.xml` que está localizado na pasta `$CATALINA_BASE/conf` seguindo assim:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/path/para/sua/jks/tomcat.jks" keystorePass="changeit" keyAlias="tomcat" keyPass="changeit"/>
```

Feito isso reinicie o tomcat e verifique se deu tudo certo acessando: `https://localhost:8443/`

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela rapidez João. Eu instalei o OpenSSL e rodei o seguinte comando no CMD: 

`C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey chavePrivada.pem -out tomcat.p12 -name tomcat`

Recebi como output essa msg:
`pkcs12: Cannot open input file fullchain.pem, No such file or directory
pkcs12: Use -help for summary.`

Comment: o fullchain.pem é a junção do seu certificado junto com o chain (certificado da sua certificadora) por exemplo se seu certificado for site.com.crt voce deve juntar ele com o CA.crt que provavelmente veio acompanhado

Comment: Desculpe, mas pra mim esse assunto é muito novo e sou muito novato. Eu não estou querendo usar um certificado de uma CA. Um self-signed Certificate pra mim já bastaria. Eu criei um .keystore cujo path é **C:\Users\Vinicius\.keystore** e modifiquei o server xml cujo path é **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf** assim:
`<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="C:\Users\Vinicius\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
`

Comment: Então em vez de fullchain.pem use suaChave.crt

Comment: Acho que estou iniciando o tomcat de maneira errada. Não consigo nem acessar o `https://localhost:8080` pra chegar na pagina default do tomcat (da erro 404). Mas se uso `http://localhost:8080/Projeto_Final/index.jsp` consigo acessar minha pagina.

Comment: Veja isso... 
https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm